# How can I randomly pick from a color array without repeats?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm mapping over an array of 15 users and creating a table row per user and want to be able pick a random color from my theme's colors array (total of 4 colors) for each user. What's the most efficient way to get a unique color so that no two same colors end up appearing next to each other?

Also is it possible to make it looks as random as possible on a larger scale? What I mean is so that it doesn't looks like I'm just going through the 4 colors in order and I end up with the same pattern every 4 users apart.

Comment: shuffle an array of the 4 colors, take from that. the 2nd part is doable but complicated. i would just re-shuffle until the new first != the old last.

Comment: I would try out solutions to your question that you simulate by hand and see what it looks like before getting too deep into a complicated shuffling thing. Having the 4 colors *not* cycle consistently might look weird.

Comment: Another thing you could do would be to start with four colors from around the color wheel, and then for each cycle have the next round use colors desaturated by like 15% or 20%.  That way you keep the same rhythm but the colors will be visibly different per cycle.

Comment: Are the colors pre-determined, or could you generate random colors using something like rgb? If you can , then you just create a Color Array before your user loop,  create a user loop with a color loop inside that generates a color until Color Array `.includes` is false, apply it to the user, add that color to the Color Array, exit user loop, fin

Comment: This question is getting downvoted, because it is attracting opinionated answers. The SO etiquette suggests that you pose a problem and post some code to show your progress, and even what problems you are facing. You can read https://stackoverflow.com/help/hot-to-ask for more information

Comment: What does "looks as random as possible" mean? I can use a perfectly random algorithm and end up with a zebra-striped table with two colors. People are not good judges of randomness.

Answer (score 0):

The question, phrased differently, is:

> How to choose a random index in of an `Array`, that is not the same as the previously chosen index?

The solution is simply to remember the previous one, and choose a different index until it's not the same. Here is a somewhat generic solution to do this:

```js
function randomOver(arr) {
  let last = 0 
  return () => {
    let i = last
    while (i == last) i = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)
    return last = i
  }
}

const colors = ['pink', 'violet', 'coral', 'khaki'],
      getIndex = randomOver(colors),
      list = document.getElementById('list')
for (let i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
  const e = document.createElement('tr'),
        x = getIndex()
  e.textContent = 'user' + i 
  e.style.backgroundColor = colors[x]
  list.appendChild(e)
}
```

```html
<table id='list'></table>
```

This is as random as possible. Does it *look* nice, though? I'm not sure